# Django REST framework and form validation

Tags: django, forms, validation, rest, frameworks

I am starting using Django REST framework, I found the framework doesn't have the same level of form validation. If I use form validation, I have the endpoint as the form, and serializes the data, which seems it is not a benefit to use the framework. How can I solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question here. Is it that you can't get the same degree of validation as you would in a normal form, or that your validation isn't working? The DRF [validation docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/) are pretty comprehensive ...

Comment: Actually I am here with, I believe, the same question.  The DRF docs which @jvc26 linked seems to mostly cover field validation.  I too would like to know how to do the equivalent of form-level validation, as Django itself is able to do.  For example, I am trying to add validation to ensure that a start date is prior to an end date.  I can't find an example anywhere.

Comment: jvc26, Yes, the DRF has a reasonable level of validation, but moving from the form validation, it lacks some features, such as form fields rendering, which is announced to be adapted as I have gathered, but don't know when.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming what you are referring to is `object` level validation. (I.e. acting on more than one field together) you need to do this in the serializer (as per [serializer docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation)) this is done by overriding:

```
def validate(self, data):
```

On the serializer class.

An example of this (from the included link):

```
def validate(self, data):
    """
    Check that the start is before the stop.
    """
    if data['start'] > data['finish']:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("finish must occur after start")
    return data
```

Comment: This worked for me -- this is exactly what I was trying to find in the docs, thanks!  Would be great if that section were linked to from the Validators page in the docs.